# How to avoid html, iframe and cross site injection in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xhtml

I have stored the data in my database as html content.

Whenever user giving the input it will inject my html.

What should I do before storing into db I need to sanitize my data. Or I can store data whatever it. While displaying in view only I need to do something for injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to refer to the XSS Cross Site Scripting [cheatsheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)

and for Rails in particular, as stated:

> The SanitizeHelper module provides a set of methods for scrubbing text of undesired HTML elements.

```
<%= sanitize @comment.body, tags: %w(strong em a), attributes: %w(href) %>
```